# Issue with reading 2d barcodes by barcode reader

Tags: c#, .net, barcode, barcode-scanner, windows

am trying to extract national identity card number from the id cards that have an encoded 2d barcode behind the card. Am trying to extract the number out of the information that am reading from the barcode scanner into my program however, am unable to do so as the location of the number lies somewhere in between the string and is making no particular pattern. am putting the card number in ** manually in the output of scanner so that i can make it clear what i want to extract. Number is sometimes coming up in 2nd line sometimes third. i just want to have the number inside the ** portion to be extracted as a string in c#. Barcode scanner am using is datalogic quickscan qd2430. Here is the sample data that i have scanned from my barcode scanner.

```
AE87816390160U1200203191614
**372011733234102**
1W986R
13031978
4


AJ78955940170U1200206181556
**374040577791302**
5N7X55
23021979
1



AH38739430112U1200203050820
102191068262003
**3740209836435**
A4Q8VN
1956-06-12
:


AZD0495911180U1200811040957
**374058860984303**
8L589M
08081990
E



AKA2849220180U1200310221058
**422017182753502**
X9R1FJ
15121978
©



AK02588170160U1200207191250
**374068678534101**
475443
02041984
-



AH77542180020U1200205291129
102011010534004
**3310010316131**
DK990V
1969-03-28
.


AJ42261000050U1200205200907
**425011609354502**
K025JR
15051973
E


AH95061210150U1200204240247
**372017211846302**
E8092N
13041961
8



AY00418831180U1200206051525
102191090871004
**4230188797841**
LQ5Z0Z
1984-06-02
©



AJ24138130150U1200210140904
**372025984571502**
94D6NS
04101981
E

AA28053210170U1200112301106
**3730311405235**
37K60G
1966    


AJ77843470150U1200206191222
**374023298202100**
D4M278
01111955
D
```

Comment: Do they always start with 3 or 4? What format do they have?

Comment: Okay.. so, is there an official format for these identifiers?

Comment: am developing this application for my company for the visitor management system. about your question am afraid no. This is an encoding policy and only the authorities making the national identity card know about it. Am just trying to extract the number and ignore the rest so that i can register the visitors based on id card number. This barcode on the back of id card contains application ref number, dob, family number and id number(one i want to extract)

Comment: You don't need to know their "encoding policy". You just need to know what the format if the identifier is. If you know the format.. you can use Regular Expressions to extract it. For example, "always starts with 3 or 4, is 12 numbers long".. etc.

Comment: this is what am trying to figure out sir but badly stuck. if only the number was in the second line fixed it could have been way easy

Comment: What country is this for?